# How to get all possible combinations of string in all orders

Tags: python

I have the following string: `abc`.

I would like to get this array as a result: `['a','b','c','ab','bc','ca','ba','cb','ac','abc','cab','cba','bac','bca']`

I have tried using `itertools.combinations()` but that doesn't give me the different orders.

Comment: Did you not try looking at the itertools [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)? There is one other function there, listed right next to `combinations`, which I believe is exactly what you need...

Comment: Combinations are order insensitive. Permutations take order into consideration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.permutations` to do this

```
>>> s = 'abc'
>>> from itertools import permutations
>>> [w for i in range(len(s)) for w in map(''.join, (permutations('abc', i+1)))]
['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use recursion with a generator:

```
def combos(d, c = []):
   if len(c) == len(d):
      yield ''.join(c)
   else:
      if c:
        yield ''.join(c)
      for i in d:
        if i not in c:
           yield from combos(d, c + [i])

print(list(combos('abc')))
```

Output:

```
['a', 'ab', 'abc', 'ac', 'acb', 'b', 'ba', 'bac', 'bc', 'bca', 'c', 'ca', 'cab', 'cb', 'cba']
```

If you wish to preserve the order, you can use `sorted`:

```
result = sorted(list(combos('abc')), key=lambda x:[len(x), x])
```

Output:

```
['a', 'b', 'c', 'ab', 'ac', 'ba', 'bc', 'ca', 'cb', 'abc', 'acb', 'bac', 'bca', 'cab', 'cba']
```